# SQLAlchemy Core Join with USING

Tags: sqlalchemy, google-bigquery

## Overview

I am trying to run a query to join some data in 3 tables in BigQuery (should apply to most relation databases like PostgreSQL as well) using SQLAlchemy Core.

## Input Data

### Table 1 (t1)

| c1 | c2 | x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 |

### Table 2 (t2)

| c1 | c2 | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |

### Table 3 (t3)

| c1 | c2 | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 6 |
| 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 8 |

## Desired Query

The query I am trying to run is

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
  t2
USING (c1, c2)
FULL OUTER JOIN
  t3
USING (c1, c2)
```

which yields (`-` indicates `null`):

| c1 | c2 | x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 6 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | - | - |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | - | - |
| 1 | 1 | - | 4 | 7 |
| 1 | 2 | - | 5 | - |
| 2 | 2 | - | - | 8 |

## Problem

The problem I am running into is that it does not seem possible to perform joins with `USING` in SQLAlchemy Core. In particular, the [join method](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.FromClause.join) only supports an `onclause` and not `USING`.

The two solutions I am attempting are:

- Try to get `USING` to work with a `TextClause`. This is proving difficult as I need to consume the resulting table, referring to the columns by name.
- Try to do the joins with the provided SQLAlchemy join method. I am unable to replicate this query using `JOIN`s with `ON` without making subqueries.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!